# Generating IVR on Asterisk without duration, get DTMF input from user and then process it

Tags: asterisk, voip

I hope cyber Asterisk gurus would be able to help me in this regard. I am trying to create an IVR filter using Asterisk. My desired configuration goal is:

1:When a user dial into the Asterisk, the user should hear IVR(but there should be no charging on initial IVR). I want to send the IVR in in initial 183 Session in progress without any duration starting on my phone.

2:Once a user input some digit via DTMF, then the call should be processed and charging etc should take place

I would really appreciate you guys input in this regard. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use power of local channel combine with NoCDR. In beginning of your IVR use NoCDR() function, and after DTMF check use Dial to local channel contex with rest of yout logic.

```
[ivr]
exten => 100,1,NoCDR()
exten => 100,n(read),Read(variable)
exten => 100,n,GotoIf($[ ${variable} = 1 ]?go_1:read)
exten => 100,n(go_1)Dial(Local/${exten}@dtmf_1_logic)

[dtmf_1_logic]
.....
```

In that case you should have one CDR from dtmf_1_logic context with call duration with you are looking for

Comment: Hi dear, thanks for your feedback. But its not what i am looking for. I want to play my IVR instead of normal RBT, once a user hear the instruction he/she enters the dtmf digit (which of course has been suggested by the IVR) and call is further processed. My goal is on initial RBT ( which is in the form of IVR in my case), there should be no charging!

Comment: You can use early media (use Playback before Answer) instead of ring. I don't think that you can receive DTMF before answering the call so try to Playback, Answer and then Read digit. But you have to know that early media is dangerous, because without answer there can be timeout from user side.

Comment: Even when i use Playback, the call begins to charge! I want the call to not charge on the IVR, charging should begin after the dtmf digit has been entered...

Comment: Can you show your dialplan? It's hard to suggest more without knowing how exactly your ivr works